# Export kriging plot as GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, raster, r, geotiff-tiff, kriging

I have performed kriging and plotted it with `ggplot`, now I want to load the plot in QGIS. For that to work I need a GeoTIFF file of my plot. How do I convert my plot into a GeoTIFF file?
EDIT: added csv file. Furthermore, I don't think I need the transformation to WGS84 as well, am I right on this?

csv: https://ufile.io/deou5t91

Here is my code:

```
###Interpolations

library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(phylin)
library(viridis)
library(gstat)
library(automap)  
library(patchwork)
library(raster)
library(fields)
library(dplyr)
norf_df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\49151\\Desktop\\ba_study_areas\\norv_343.csv",
                      header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")

max(norf_df['Z'])
min(norf_df['Z'])

hist(norf_df$Z, breaks = 10, xlab = "subsidence", main = "Histogram of subsidence")


## make sf object of data
crs = st_crs("EPSG:32632")

norf_df_sf <- st_as_sf(norf_df, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = "OGC:CRS84")%>%
  st_transform(crs)

##grid to be interpolated

grd_100_sf <- norf_df_sf %>%
  st_make_grid(
    cellsize = c(20, 20),
    what = "centers"
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.))

##get the coordinates and values of Original Data

data <- norf_df_sf %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::select(X,Y,Z)

##get coords of grid

grd <- grd_100_sf %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::select(X,Y)

##IDW Interpolation

i <- phylin::idw(data[,3],
         data[,1:2],
         grd) %>% 
  cbind(grd)



#display interpolation in WGS84

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = i, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, col = Z), size = 3) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = heat.colors(15)) +
  coord_sf(crs=crs, datum = st_crs(4326))

#tilled plot 


ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = i, aes(x = X, y= Y, fill = Z)) +
  coord_sf(crs=crs, datum = st_crs(4326)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "B", limits = c(-40, 5))

# Variogram
v_emp_OK <- gstat::variogram(
  Z~1,
  as(norf_df_sf, "Spatial") # switch from {sf} to {sp}
)

plot(v_emp_OK)

v_mod_OK <- automap::autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(norf_df_sf, "Spatial"))$var_model

plot(automap::autofitVariogram(Z~1, as(norf_df_sf, "Spatial")))

grd_100_sf_sp <- as(grd_100_sf, "Spatial")
gridded(grd_100_sf_sp) <- TRUE 
grd_100_sf_sp <- as(grd_100_sf_sp, "SpatialPixels")

Ok <- krige(
  Z~1, 
  as(norf_df_sf, "Spatial"),
  grd_100_sf_sp,
  model = v_mod_OK
)

Ok_df <- as.data.frame(Ok)
```

Comment: Could you share a piece of your .csv to get the same result ?

Comment: inverse-distance weighted interpolation is not kriging.

Comment: Don't do `library(tidyverse)`. Installing tidyverse is a quick way to get a large number of packages, but attaching them all is a bad idea which will stomp on other functions. Always use individual `library` calls for only the packages you need.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion! I just copied a part of my script, which includes kriging and idw of the ggplot, which is the part I'dlike to save as a geotiff. But you are absolutely right, kriging is not IDW. I edit the kriging part too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the output *data* as a TIFF and not the "plot" with all its axes and lines etc... You can get the Viridis colour palette in QGIS if you want to style it that way.

Use the `rasterFromXYZ` function from the `raster` package to create a raster from your XYZ matrix. The return from the `idw` function seems to be `ZXY` order so the columns are rearranged first. Then give it the projection and save as a GeoTIFF which (loaded into QGIS and mapped over OpenStreetMap...) puts it in an airfield SW of Koln...

```
library(raster)
ir = rasterFromXYZ(i[,c(2,3,1)])
projection(ir) = st_crs(grd_100_sf)$wkt
writeRaster(ir,"ir.tiff")
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks simple! Does it work with my ordinary kriging ("OK") or ordinary dataframe ("ok_df") as well?

Comment: It works with any output that is, or can be converted to, a three-column matrix or data frame of gridded X,Y values with a Z value. Check the documentation for each function to see what its output is. Most likely it will generate something you can use with this.

Comment: Thank you very much, got it to work! Final question: the resolution does seem slightly pixelated. On the documention I see an optional numeric variable for the resolution "res". How do I set this one to get a better plot? with res=c(300,300) I get an error saying "cell size not regular" and I'd like to understand it.

Comment: The pixels should be the pixels of the grid you generated, probably from the `cellsize` option in `st_make_grid`. The `rasterFromXYZ` function looks at the X and Y coordinate vector and thinks "Hmm this looks like a 20x20 grid" and creates a raster of that resolution from the differences in the X and Y values. Its usually correct, especially from data generated from grids in the first place, but the `res` option can be used if your data is sparse, and not the full grid, which isn't the case here.